# Laravel 4 - Case Sensitive Database Columns

Tags: mysql, database, postgresql, laravel, case-sensitive

Hi i am having problem with the case sensitive eloquent, i am developing i small program that can use mysql and postgres databases, The problem is if i use mysql everything is okay, but if i use Postgressql, i must change the columns names to the real names on the database.

```
Mysql Engine :
$clientsName = array_fetch ($clientsall, 'Name') ;
$clientsId = array_fetch ($clientsall, 'ClientId') ;

Postgres Engine:

$clientsName = array_fetch ($clientsall, 'name') ;
$clientsId = array_fetch ($clientsall, 'clientid') ;
```

How can change to always does not need the case sensitives database columns name?

Comment: can you not keep to one set say lower case and using an underscore to separate items if required. client_id, this will and then can solve an issue swopping as i have done when i had case sensitive issues.

Comment: The problem is that i accessing database of Bacula - Bacula.org, and i don't have the control of that database, i think bacula on mysql create the columns name like clientid and on Postgres create has ClientId. So what i need is something that i can change via PHP:PDO setting to assume the diference –

Answer (score 0):

Laravel is not responsible for case sensitivity of database engine. MySQL and PostgreSQL have different rules in this case.

You have several options to write better code :

1. Use naming standards : Laravel Eloquent attributes and SQL column names should be snake case
2. Use OOP and Eloquent getters instead of parsing raw SQL results. Eloquent is an abstraction layer that allow you to change your database engine with the same syntax.

Comment: The problem is that i accessing database of Bacula - Bacula.org, and i don't have the control of that database, i think bacula on mysql create the columns name like clientid and on Postgres create has ClientId. So what i need is something that i can change via PHP:PDO setting to assume the diference

Comment: Then, you have to use the second solution I propose : abstract your DB access by using OOP. Create an object `Client` and use getters to access its attributes. You can build custom getter in Eloquent models like that : http://laravel.com/docs/eloquent#accessors-and-mutators. I can't say more without more information about your use case.

Answer (score 0):

You can put field names in variables, using MySQL notation. Then check if the db engine is MySQL or PostgreSQL. If it is PostgreSQL do $fieldname = strtolower( $filedname ). For example:

```
$f_Name = 'Name';
$f_ClientID = 'ClientID';

if ( $postgres ) {
    $f_Name = strtolower($f_Name);
    $f_ClientID = strtolower($f_ClientID);
}

//Both Engines :
$clientsName = array_fetch ($clientsall, $f_Name) ;
$clientsId = array_fetch ($clientsall, $f_ClientId) ;
```

Comment: Yes that is i nice approach. Thanks